# Is there a Filter listener support in JasperSoft?

Tags: java, filter, jasper-reports, lazy-loading

I am trying to use Jaspersoft with my application using custom data-source, my use-case is something like:

1. My custom data-source gets the data from a rest service and the data is very huge like some 100 million rows.
2. What I have achieved so far is get the whole data which JasperSoft saves it in cache and generate some ad-hoc reports/charts out of it.
3. So, if user wants to filter anything, the data is filtered from the data present in report or cache (I am not sure about the real concept of filtering)

What I want is some kind of lazy loading.

Like to get first 1 million rows at once and generate some report out of it (Only for crossTabs/Table reports). And, when user filters, my custom-datasource (Java Code) is able to detect and read that filter in code, form a rest query parameters out of that filter, get the filtered data and fill the report. Kind of a listener on the filter but should also have the capability to re-fill the report.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Regards,

Ashit